# java работа с текстом

Tags: java, строки

**Есть текстовый фаил, в котором записано следующие:**

---

**Вопрос : как вырвать из текста нужные мне строки?
Строки, которые мне нужно получить:**

1. 03:30 Хьюстон Рокетс - Голден Стэйт Уорриорз 126:121 (25:26, 33:23,
   33:35, 21:28, 14:9) (ОТ)
2. 22:30 Филадельфия Севенти Сиксерс - Торонто Рэпторс 96:101 (21:24,
   24:23, 30:28, 21:26)
3. 22:30 Хозяева (очки) - Гости (очки) 208:217 (54:53, 54:51, 44:55,
   56:58)

```html
<div class="pro_details padding det_details"> 
 <strong></strong> 03:30 Хьюстон Рокетс - Голден Стэйт Уорриорз 126:121 (25:26, 33:23, 33:35, 21:28, 14:9) (ОТ) 
 <br>
 <br> Первый фол Хьюстон Рокетс; Первый подбор Хьюстон Рокетс; Какая команда наберет очки первой Хьюстон Рокетс; Гонка до 5 очков Голден Стэйт Уорриорз; Гонка до 10 очков Голден Стэйт Уорриорз; Гонка до 20 очков Голден Стэйт Уорриорз; Гонка до 30 очков Хьюстон Рокетс; Гонка до 40 очков Хьюстон Рокетс; Гонка до 50 очков Хьюстон Рокетс; Гонка до 75 очков Хьюстон Рокетс; Гонка до 100 очков Голден Стэйт Уорриорз; Первый реализованный трёхочковый бросок Голден Стэйт Уорриорз; Первые набранные очки 2-х очк. бросок; Гонка до 5-ти очков (1-я четверть) Голден Стэйт Уорриорз; Гонка до 5-ти очков (2-я четверть) Хьюстон Рокетс; Гонка до 5-ти очков (3-я четверть) Голден Стэйт Уорриорз; Гонка до 5-ти очков (4-я четверть) Голден Стэйт Уорриорз; Гонка до 10-ти очков (1-я четверть) Голден Стэйт Уорриорз; Гонка до 10-ти очков (2-я четверть) Хьюстон Рокетс; Гонка до 10-ти очков (3-я четверть) Голден Стэйт Уорриорз; Гонка до 10-ти очков (4-я четверть) Голден Стэйт Уорриорз; Гонка до 15-ти очков (1-я четверть) Голден Стэйт Уорриорз; Гонка до 15-ти очков (2-я четверть) Хьюстон Рокетс; Гонка до 15-ти очков (3-я четверть) Хьюстон Рокетс; Гонка до 15-ти очков (4-я четверть) Голден Стэйт Уорриорз; Гонка до 20-ти очков (1-я четверть) Голден Стэйт Уорриорз; Гонка до 20-ти очков (2-я четверть) Хьюстон Рокетс; Гонка до 20-ти очков (3-я четверть) Хьюстон Рокетс; Гонка до 20-ти очков (4-я четверть) Голден Стэйт Уорриорз; Дрэймонд Грин 19; Дюрант К. 46; Игуодала А. 16; Карри Ст. 17; Томпсон К. 16; Гордон Э. 30; Капела К. 13; Пол К. 14; Такер П. 7; Харден Дж. 41; Дрэймонд Грин 11; Дюрант К. 3; Игуодала А. 5; Карри Ст. 3; Томпсон К. 8; Гордон Э. 2; Капела К. 11; Пол К. 8; Такер П. 12; Харден Дж. 9; Дрэймонд Грин 10; Дюрант К. 6; Игуодала А. 3; Карри Ст. 4; Томпсон К. 2; Гордон Э. 2; Капела К. 1; Пол К. 7; Такер П. 3; Харден Дж. 6
 <br>
 <br>22:30 Филадельфия Севенти Сиксерс - Торонто Рэпторс 96:101 (21:24, 24:23, 30:28, 21:26) 
 <br>
 <br> Какая команда наберет очки первой Торонто Рэпторс; Гонка до 5 очков Торонто Рэпторс; Гонка до 10 очков Филадельфия Севенти Сиксерс; Гонка до 20 очков Торонто Рэпторс; Гонка до 30 очков Торонто Рэпторс; Гонка до 40 очков Торонто Рэпторс; Гонка до 50 очков Торонто Рэпторс; Гонка до 75 очков Филадельфия Севенти Сиксерс; Гонка до 100 очков Торонто Рэпторс; Первые набранные очки Штрафной бросок; Гонка до 5-ти очков (1-я четверть) Торонто Рэпторс; Гонка до 5-ти очков (2-я четверть) Торонто Рэпторс; Гонка до 5-ти очков (3-я четверть) Торонто Рэпторс; Гонка до 5-ти очков (4-я четверть) Филадельфия Севенти Сиксерс; Гонка до 10-ти очков (1-я четверть) Филадельфия Севенти Сиксерс; Гонка до 10-ти очков (2-я четверть) Торонто Рэпторс; Гонка до 10-ти очков (3-я четверть) Филадельфия Севенти Сиксерс; Гонка до 10-ти очков (4-я четверть) Торонто Рэпторс; Гонка до 15-ти очков (1-я четверть) Торонто Рэпторс; Гонка до 15-ти очков (2-я четверть) Торонто Рэпторс; Гонка до 15-ти очков (3-я четверть) Филадельфия Севенти Сиксерс; Гонка до 15-ти очков (4-я четверть) Торонто Рэпторс; Гонка до 20-ти очков (1-я четверть) Торонто Рэпторс; Гонка до 20-ти очков (2-я четверть) Торонто Рэпторс; Гонка до 20-ти очков (3-я четверть) Филадельфия Севенти Сиксерс; Гонка до 20-ти очков (4-я четверть) Торонто Рэпторс; Газоль М. 16; Дэнни Грин 11; Леонард К. 39; Лоури К. 14; Сиакам П. 9; Батлер Дж. 29; Редик Дж. 19; Симмонс Б. 10; Харрис Т. 16; Эмбиид Дж. 11; Газоль М. 5; Дэнни Грин 4; Леонард К. 14; Лоури К. 6; Сиакам П. 3; Батлер Дж. 11; Редик Дж. 3; Симмонс Б. 5; Харрис Т. 6; Эмбиид Дж. 8; Газоль М. 3; Леонард К. 5; Лоури К. 7; Сиакам П. 2; Батлер Дж. 4; Редик Дж. 2; Симмонс Б. 4; Харрис Т. 4; Эмбиид Дж. 7
 <br>
 <br> 
 <blockquote> 
 </blockquote> 
</div>
<div class="pro_details padding det_details"> 
 <strong></strong> 22:30 Хозяева (очки) - Гости (очки) 208:217 (54:53, 54:51, 44:55, 56:58) 
 <br>
 <br> Кол-во побед вторых команд 2; Кол-во побед первых команд в 1-й четверти 1; Кол-во побед вторых команд в 1-й четверти 1; Кол-во побед первых команд в 1-й половине 1; Кол-во побед вторых команд в 1-й половине 1; Тотал самой результативной четверти 67; Тотал самой нерезультативной четверти 41
 <br>
 <br> 
 <blockquote> 
 </blockquote> 
</div>
```

---

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}\\:\\d{2}\\b").matcher(dataString);
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
```

Подскажите как грамотно составить само регулярное выражение , чтобы достать нужную мне информацию.

Comment: Судя по всему, это не просто текстовый файл, а это именно html-страница. Такие вещи не стоит парсить регулярками, нужно использовать разные библиотеки для работы с html ( ну или xml)

Comment: Вы правы, я использовал jsoup чтобы спарсить эту страницу, просто я не смог средствами библиотеки jsoup достать нужные мне строки и поэтому решил попробовать регулярками, в принципе если что так что так проблема остается:(

Comment: Уж простите, <br> нельзя использовать. Для каждого абзаца использовать <p>текст</p>. Ещё непонятно по какому критерию вам нужно получить строки - дополните вопрос.

Comment: Критерий: В начале идет время матча потом название первой  команды - название второй команды , дальше идет общий счет встречи и после идет в скобках счет по периодам

Answer (score 0):

Так попробуй:

```
(?<=\>)\s*\d\d:\d\d.*$
```